# How to group entries, calculate frequencies and averages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency

I want to check how many times `key1`, `key2` and `key3` were repeated in `df`, and for each key to estimate an average value of `num`.

Now I can create `keys_summary` for only single key (e.g. `key1`). How can I count the frequency of all keys in a single line? Also, how to add the average values of `num` into the `keys_summary`?

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(['aaa abc','aaa cba','bbb bbc','aaa cba','bbb bbc'])
s2 = pd.Series([3,5,1,4,0])

df = pd.DataFrame({'descr': s1, 'num': s2})

print df

k1 = pd.Series(['aaa','abc','cba'])
k2 = pd.Series(['bbb','bbc'])
k3 = pd.Series(['ddd','ddc'])

keys = pd.DataFrame({'key1': k1,'key2': k2, 'key3': k3})

print keys

keys_summary = df['descr'].groupby(lambda x : x in keys['key1']).count()

print keys_summary
```

The expected result must be the following:

```
keys_summary
     count   avg_num
key1 3       4
key2 2       1
key3 0       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: here's an alternative answer that does not rely on building a permutation list, rather it expects that the values for each key be disjoint (that is, no value belongs to more than one string). Given the dataframes `df` and `keys`:

```
keys_summary = pd.DataFrame()
for col in keys:
   keys_summary[col] = df[df.descr.apply(lambda x: any(word in x.split() for word in keys[col]))].describe().num
keys_summary = keys_summary.transpose()
```

This results in the same dataframe as given below, for the example in the question.

---

Given your dataframe of `keys`, you can generate lists of permutations 2 by 2 (if `descr` is always two key-substrings, that is - else some minor modifications might be necessary) and then check for them in `df`. Use the `describe` method to get the stats.

```
import itertools
#df and keys as given
key_dict = {}
for col in keys:
    perms = []
    for (a,b) in itertools.permutations(keys[col].tolist(), 2):
        perms.append(str(a) + ' ' + str(b))
    key_dict[col] = perms
```

Then you use this dictionary and the `df` dataframe to generate a `keys_summary`:

```
keys_summary = pd.DataFrame()
for k,v in key_dict.items():
    keys_summary[k] = df[df.descr.isin(v)].describe().num
keys_summary = keys_summary.transpose()
```

This results in:

```
      count  mean       std  min   25%  50%   75%  max
key3      0   NaN       NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
key2      2   0.5  0.707107    0  0.25  0.5  0.75    1
key1      3   4.0  1.000000    3  3.50  4.0  4.50    5
```

You can drop the columns min, 25%, max, etc. if you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks, descr substrings can have different length.

Comment: If you know the maximum number n of substrings in descr, you can generate the n-permutations of the key-valyes and then substitute the check for 'isin(v)' for 'is a substring of any value in v'. Sorry that I can't help you code that right now, but I might get around to it later today if you still need it

Comment: Also, I checked if s1 = pd.Series(['aaa abc','aaa cba ddd','bbb bbc','aaa cba','bbb bbc']), then result is the same. But notice that 'aaa cba ddd' contains key3 and key1, however in the summary key3 is still equal to 0.

Comment: No, the problem is that I cannot know n apriori. That's the case. Also substrings might be really long. Therefore, I cannot create so many permutations. Do you know any approach without permutations? Maybe it's possible just to split df['descr']?

Comment: I updated the question with something that might help you.  I'll leave the original answer up cause it can help people with similar cases with treatable low values of n.